# Есть ли аналог GetKeyDown , но с touch

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли аналог GetKeyDown , но с тачами.
Уже пару часов роюсь в инете ,но так и не смог найти.
Нужно что бы после того как игрок отпустил палец с экрана происходило действие.

```
(If ...)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [TouchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html), в котором лежит перечисление видов нажатий на экран.

```
Began       - Палец коснулся экрана.
Moved       - Палец передвинулся по экрану.
Stationary  - Палец коснулся экрана, но не сдвинулся.
Ended       - Палец только что оторван от экрана. Это последняя фаза нажатий.
Canceled    - Система отменила отслеживание касаний.
```

и конкретное применение описано в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html)

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector2 direction;
    public bool directionChosen;
    void Update() {
        // Если есть касание
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // Определяем вид касания и его зависимую логику
            switch (touch.phase) {
                // Record initial touch position.
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    startPos = touch.position;
                    directionChosen = false;
                    break;

                // Determine direction by comparing the current touch position with the initial one.
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    direction = touch.position - startPos;
                    break;

                // Report that a direction has been chosen when the finger is lifted.
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    directionChosen = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (directionChosen) {
            // Что-то происходит тут если выбрано направление...
        }
    }
}
```